# excel import txt file - decimal symbol not recognized

Tags: excel, load

My .txt file contains rows like this:

1,2.10985,1.11142

2,2.10729,1.10968

3,2.08096,1.08162

4,2.07895,1.08044

5,2.07935,1.07885

6,2.08214,1.0822

7,2.07131,1.07032

However, after loading the data via 'Data->From Text/Csv' the columns look like this:

[image]

Changing the column type to number did not help.

Also in my control panel, the decimal symbol is a comma.

What can I do to fix this?

EDIT:
Here is a screenshot of my Region settings. I can also upload the pictures in Englisch if neccessary. My country is Germany.

[image]

Comment: I can load that data with no issues: it comes in as a proper floating point number (2.12, 3.45). The separator option is only for numbers above 1,000, so I don't believe that is the issue. My guess is that your decimal character `.` is not the ASCII decimal (46), but rather a different character. Try opening a text editor (like NotePad) and then copy/paste the data into Excel. The next step will then use TextToColumns on the Data Ribbon and see how that handles it.

Comment: When using the wizard to import from text, in one of the steps there is a button called `Advanced`. Click there and choose dot as decimal separator and comma as thousands separator. That way it will be read as English format but adapted to your local settings posted in the image.

Comment: Please edit your question to  **copy/paste as text** an example of several rows of your data.  Add a screenshot of the window that opens after you select `Data=>From Text/CSV`.  Also, please, your **country** specification in `Windows/Region Settings` (and any customizations you may have done). As noted by @PeterT, I cannot reproduce your problem, even with my decimal separator set to "comma".  Your Excel system separator setting will have no effect. The value needs to be properly interpreted at the time of import.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @Ron Rosenfeld: I uploaded the postings you required for specification.

Comment: @Simon That is unusual.  If I set my regional settings to `German(Germany)`, and use your method of importing the data, the values get properly translated, with the dot being translated into a decimal (comma).  Since you **copy/pasted** the csv data, that should have eliminated the possibility of the dot in the csv file not being ASCII 46.  Although, if it was something else, it should have shown up on the import.  What happens if you set your regional settings to English(United States)?

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld The issue is the same after setting the regional settings to English

Comment: Must be an issue either with your data or some obscure setting in Excel. Suggest either sharing the actual CSV file or possibly try running Excel in safe mode.

Comment: Is is not a csv file but a txt file. But this makes probably no difference.

Comment: Correctd: makes no difference.  If there is confidential information, please share a file with that information redacted, but which still causes the problem on your computer.

Comment: Which file are you referring to?

Comment: The txt file you are having a problem importing.

Comment: How can I upload the txt file here? I do not see an option when trying to edit the question.

Comment: You need to upload it to some public sharing site such as OneDrive or Dropbox, and then post a link here

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D1_fLm-IqQTBQ-Xd-zqRnXZIdwIn86b1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I added a link to Google Drive here. Thank zou for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your downloaded file, and setting my Regional settings to `German(Germany)`, I can reproduce your problem.

You will need to tell Power Query (that's what you are using when you do the `Data=>from text/csv` operation) that the source file is using US-centric values.

To do this:

- When the window opens, instead of <kbd>Load</kbd> select <kbd>Transform Data</kbd>.
- When the PQ Editor opens, select `Home=>Advanced Editor`
- Change the second line to read:

```
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, 
    {"Column2", type number}, {"Column3", type number}},"en-US")
```

- Note that we have changed both the data type and added the culture argument at the end

  - This could be done from the UI. I will leave you to explore that.

The entire code in my Advanced Editor (might be different in yours due to language):

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\Invariants_at_QPs.txt"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, 
    {"Column2", type number}, {"Column3", type number}},"en-US")
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

And a screeshot of part of the results:

[image]

Comment: It works for me as well. Just one last question: how did you figure out that the source file uses US-centric values?

Comment: @Simon Visual examination of the file.  It is using the dot for decimal separator.  What I don't understand was why I did not have a problem using the text that you had pasted into your question.